# Durrett Exercise 4.2.10 (i)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, martingales

> **[Durrett Exercise 4.2.10 (i)]**
> Let $(X_n,\mathcal{F}_n)$ be a supermartingale. Let $N_0=-1$ and for $j\geq 1$, let
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}N_{2j-1}&=\inf\{m>N_{2j-2}:X_m\leq a\},\\N_{2j}&=\inf\{m>N_{2j-1}:X_m\geq b\}.\end{aligned}
> \end{equation}
> Let $Y_n=1$ for $0\leq n<N_1$ and for $j\geq 1$
> \begin{equation}
> Y_n=\begin{cases}(b/a)^{j-1}(X_n/a)&\text{for}N_{2j-1}\leq n<N_{2j},\\(b/a)^j&\text{for}N_{2j}\leq n<N_{2j+1}\end{cases}
> \end{equation}
> Use the switch principle and induction to show $Z_n^j=Y_{n\wedge N_j}$ is a supermartingale.

> **[Switching Principle]**
> If $X_n,Y_n$ are supermartingales, and $N$ a stopping time with $X^1_N\geq X^2_N$, then
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}&X_n^11_{(N>n)}+X_n^21_{(N\leq n)}\text{is a supermartingale,}\\&X_n^11_{(N\geq n)}+X_n^21_{(N<n)}\text{is a supermartingale.}\end{aligned}
> \end{equation}

This post [How to prove Dubin's inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4281820/how-to-prove-dubins-inequality) gave a proof of this exercise. Following its route,

\begin{aligned}
Z^1_n&=1_{(N_1>n)}+\left(\frac{X_{N_1}}{a}\right)1_{(N_1\leq n)}\\
Z^2_n&=Z^1_n1_{(N_1>n)}+\left(\frac{X_n}{a}\right)1_{(N_1\geq n)}1_{(N_2>n)}+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^21_{(N_2\leq n)}\\
Z^3_n&=Z^2_n1_{(N_3>n)}+\left(\frac{b}{a}\frac{X_{N_3}}{a}\right)1_{(N_3\leq n)}\\
\dots
\end{aligned}

If I understand correctly, there's no reason for $\left(\frac{X_{N_{2j-1}}}{a}\right)$ to be supermartingales and hence to use the switching principle, since [Is $X_N$ a martingale if $N$ is a stopping time?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4861897/is-x-n-a-martingale-if-n-is-a-stopping-time?noredirect=1#comment10364117_4861897) is false in general. Is there any other ways to solve this exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $X_N 1_{(N \leq n)} = X_{N\wedge n} 1_{(N \leq n)}$ and if $X_n$ is a supermartingale and $N$ is a stopping time, then $X_{N\wedge n}$ is a supermartingale.